# Amazon s3 policy document for any file type and maintain the name not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to modify the policy on the following web [Amazon S3 Browser-Based Uploads](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/post/post_sample.html) to maintain the name of the file when uploaded into amazon as explain in [here](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434), however when i modify the policy to something like:

```
{
  "expiration": "2015-01-01T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "MYBUCKETNAME" },
    {"acl": "public-read" },
    ["eq", "$key", "uploads/"],
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "text/"],
  ]
}
```

and then in the form to something like:

```
<input type="text" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}" />
```

But i am keep getting the error

AccessDeniedInvalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$key", "uploads/"]

I just dont understand what I am doing wrong, as the tutorial says that leaving ${filename}, will maintain the name.

Question 2:

How can I modify the content type () to accept any file type, well I am interested in uploading only doc, docx, pdf and images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this policy given below

```
{
  "expiration": "2015-01-01T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "MYBUCKETNAME" },
    {"acl": "public-read" },
    ["starts-with", "$key", "uploads/"],
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
  ]
}
```

This policy should work if you have the right user policy in place.